# Can I dynamically adjust the height of a css set div border?

Tags: css, dynamic, html, height, border

Ok so I have a div that contains a few forms that have dynamically generated content. There are categories, that if you click on, slide/toggle down to reveal that categories sub-contents, or projects. Right now, I have it setup so that if the height of the div expands to exceed a set amount, a scroll bar shows up at the side, and the user can scroll down and see the content.

NOW I am being asked to get rid of the scroll bar, and just have the div's border (which is just 1px set in the css) height adjust dynamically with the height of the div's content...can I even do that? Is there some sort of jquery animation that would allow that? A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: You can do that, but why would you want to? Having a div's border resize based on content would be exceedingly strange. And how are you supposed to see the rest of the content if you don't have a scrollbar?

Comment: My thoughts exactly! But my boss wants me to try it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now probably have a height set on the container div:

```
#container {
height: xxpx;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Just change that to a min-height:

```
#container {
min-height: xxpx;
overflow: visible;
}
```

The div will be at least xx pixels, and grow to fit after that.

Comment: It seems as though that should be working, but The scroll bar still shows up at the side...is that what it should be doing?

Comment: No, i'm sorry. I meant overflow: visible;.